# UITableView to display keyvalue pairs

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a list of name and values I need to display. It's difficult to maintain lots of labels and associated content textfields in IB so I'm thinking of using  UITableView. Is there a way to fix the labels for cells, then just either bind to an NSDictionary and display the key/value names or fix the cells and labels in a UITableView?

Comment: How many items per cell do you have? You could easily use the existing cell functionality if you dont have too many (by using multiple lines, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to the table view as you might do when writing OS/X apps, but the two methods below, in your UITableView's datasource should do the trick:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * dict;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * sortedKeys;

- (void) setDict: (NSDictionary *) dict 
{
    _dict = dict;
    self.sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sortedKeys count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath: indexPath];

    NSString * key = self.sortedKeys[indexPath.row];
    NSString * value = dict[key];

    cell.textLabel.text = key;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = value;

    return cell;
}
```

---

*or in Swift*

```
var sortedKeys: Array<String> = []
var dict:Dictionary<String, String> = [:] {
didSet {
    sortedKeys = sort(Array(dict.keys)) {$0.lowercaseString < $1.lowercaseString}
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sortedKeys.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    let key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row] as String
    let value = dict[key] as String

    cell.textLabel.text = key
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = value

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is it better to sort the dictionary once (ie when being set) instead of sorting it each time cellforrow is called?

Answer (score 1):

Just read this [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) and everything will be clear for you.

You can use next table view cell's types : `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` or `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`. They have two labels as you need (one for key and one for value).

Or you can create your own cell style and set values for labels using there tags.

Comment: Thanks. For reference, on `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, the label is the widest part, on `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`, the key is the widest part (best if you have short values with long names).